# Ubuntu 13.04 works on a uefi pc?

Tags: uefi

Can ubuntu 13.04 works on a uefi pc? or i've to modify the uefi & boot partitions?

Answer (score 1):

In an UEFI PC, ubuntu identifies such PC and while installation suggest the type and nature of partitions you need to create to work in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.04 will indeed work on a UEFI system and create it's own partitions to work properly during install...  If you have a 64-bit processor be sure to download and install Ubuntu 64-bit to be sure...